# Loading tidyverse leads to error message there is no package called 'readr'

Tags: r, readr

I'm still new to R and just installed R on a new MacBook Pro and received the following error message when loading tidy verse. Grateful for any help!

```
library(tidyverse)
```

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
> there is no package called ‘readr’

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could install the dependencies as well

```
 install.packages('tidyverse', dependencies = TRUE)
```

or install `readr` with `dependencies`

```
install.packages('readr', dependencies = TRUE)
```